# Liquibase upgrade

Tags: java, database-migration, liquibase

When migrating to version 3.8.0, changesets generate different hash sums and when I start the application I get an exception: Validation Failed: 1185 change sets check sum. This makes it impossible to migrate to the new version. Maybe there is a special solution for this? Didn't find information in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The [clearCheckSums](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/clearchecksums.html) command may help you.  It will clear the current check sums in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table in your database and calculate and insert new values on your next update.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `validCheckSum` to your change set. If you provide the last checksum, from the database or a failure log in this value liquibase will not execute the changeset.